# R glm() vector too large

Tags: r, glm, r-caret

I am trying to run a binary logistic regression in R on a very large set of data. I keep running into memory problems. I have tried many different packages to try to circumvent this issue, but am still stuck. I thought packages such as caret and biglm would help. But they gave me the same memory error. Why is it that when I start with a dataset with 300,000 rows and 300 columns and proceed to subset it to 50,000 rows and 120 columns, it still requires the same amount of memory? It makes no sense. I have no way of replicating the data since it is sensitive information, but most of the variables are factors. Below are some examples I have tried

```
model = bigglm(f, data = reg, na.action = na.pass, family = binomial(link=logit), chunksize = 5000)
```

But I get:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 128.7 Gb

```
MyControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedCV", index = MyFolds, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, classProbs = TRUE)  
fit = train(f, data = reg, family = binomial, trControl = MyControl)
```

Comment: Create a fake dataset and show the code you have tried. Edit your question to show us what specifically is not working and the steps you have taken to try and circumvent the issue.

Comment: Also, please add information regarding what version of R you use, what architecture and OS you're on, and what you have tried in order to fix the memory problems.

Comment: If you don't know much about the actual statistics involved in fitting linear models, you may not be aware that categorical variables with n levels are recoded into n-1 binary indicator columns. If even one of your variables is a factor with a very large number of values, you will consistently use lots of memory. Variables like that are of dubious value anyway, and if they exist you should be seriously rethinking the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 128.7 Gb" doesn't meant that R cannot allocate a total memory of 128.7 Gb.

Quoting [Patrick Burns](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf):

> "It is because R has already allocated a lot of memory successfully.
>   The error message is about how much memory R was going after at the
>   point where it failed".

So it is your interpretation of the error that is wrong. Even though the size of the problems might be very different, they are probably both just too big for your computer, and the amount of memory displayed in the error message is unrelated to the size of your problem.